# Hibernate query for select records based on the date?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm using hibernate for the data access layer,
so i have to write HQL query for the following SQL query.

> select * from MyTable where my_date >= '16-SEP-2012'

It is working fine.. For this i have written HQL query as follows,

> From MyTable as NB where NB.my_date >=date

It is throwing an error..

> From MyTable as NB where NB.my_date >=Mon Mar 07 00:00:00 IST 1
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Mar

How to write HQL query for this.. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :date, since your current code is a syntax error. If it still doesn't work, try using a yyyy-MM-dd format - it might be a locale issue. Also be sure to set the parameter properly, you Did not include that part of your code.

Comment: date of HQL is dynamic. So i just directly used it..What would be the syntax to execute it successfully?

Comment: Oh you concate strings? Then your date needs to be insides single quotes. I strongly recommend using proper parameters instead. Criteria api is a good alternative aswell for dynamic queries.

Comment: Be ware that constructing queries like that can potentially leave you open to sql injektion. Less so with jpa but still a very bad practice.